# VBA Query using ADODB returning different results on different computers

Tags: oracle, vba, excel, adodb

In VBA macro in Excel I have an issue where the exact same query with the exact same database credentials are returning different results depending on what computer the script is being executed.  Some pull all of the correct results, others have results missing.

If we execute the query using Toad or any other tool that can execute oracle it has worked correctly on every machine tested.

So far we have found out that the following things are not causing the issue:

- Oracle Driver version (instant client vs full both tested no correlation found)
- Excel versions (everyone at my company has the same build of excel)
- VBA project references are the same.
- Confirmed all machines are pointing to the correct database.
- ODBC Settings are the same

All machines tested are running Excel 2010 on windows 7, The Database is Oracle 11,

Here is the script

```
Dim cn
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim rs
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
cn.ConnectionString = "DSN=#####;UID=####;PWD=#####;DBQ=######;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F"`  

`cn.Open`

`Set rs = cn.Execute(SQLfinal)`

Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Integer

fldCount = rs.Fields.Count
For iCol = 1 To fldCount
    Sheets("8. Data").Cells(12, iCol).Value = rs.Fields(iCol - 1).Name
Next    
Sheets("8. ####").Cells(13, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs 
rs.Close

Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close

Rows("12:12").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Comment: What type of query is `SQLFinal` (view/table) ? Are you using the exact same login across the computers which show different results? Is it always the same set of results which are missing, and is there anything specific about the missing results?

Comment: Hi Tim,  SQLFinal is a table query.  We are using the same database login across all of the computers. It is always the same set of results that are missing. I have not been able to identify any specific attribute that would make these results different.

Comment: If you convert the query to a "select count(something) from..." does it give the same number across the different machines?  Does the query involve any dates in the select clause ?

Comment: we are getting the same reduced set of values on some of the computers and on others we are getting the full set.  So while counts are the same for each group they differ between the two.

Comment: Have you tried switching to a DSN-less connection string?

Comment: I'll try that, is there a good resource on how to do this in VBA?  so far all of my attempts with a DSN-less connection string  have been unsuccessful.

Comment: As long as the Oracle client and drivers are installed then I've not had any problem in the past.  Eg: a connection string like `Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Password=PWHere;User ID=UserHere;Data Source=TNSEntryHere;` usually works no problem.

Comment: This looks to have solved the problem, Which is great!!  Thanks a million Tim.   Do you know why doing this solves this problem?

Comment: You're using a lot of options in your original DSN-based connection string: I have no idea what any of those do, so it's difficult to suggest anything.  Also, without seeing the exact SQL there's a whole set of potential clues missing.

Comment: I had a similar problem that was solved by ensuring that the count(foo) item in the SELECT list, had an alias named for it, i.e. SELECT count(foo) as MyCount.  Someone knew that the lack of an alias can confuse ADODB.